# Изменить значение атрибута с приращением в Python

Tags: python, классы

Почему выдает: AttributeError: 'Restaurant' object has no attribute 'increment_number_served'

```py
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self, restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        self.restaurant_name = restaurant_name
        self.cuisine_type = cuisine_type
        self.number_served = 0
    def describe_restaurant(self):
        print('В ресторане ' + self.restaurant_name.title() + ' ' + self.cuisine_type + ' кухня!')
    def open_restaurant(self):
        print('Мы открылись!')
    def served_nubmer(self):
        print('Количество уже обслуженных посетителей: ' + str(self.number_served))
    def set_number_served(self, the_sum):
        self.number_served = the_sum
        def increment_number_served(self, total):
            self.number_served += total
restaurant = Restaurant('Ali-Oli', 'итальянская')
restaurant_1 = Restaurant('kimchi', 'корейская')
restaurant_2 = Restaurant('Frukt', 'въетнамская')

print('\nПриглашаем вас в ресторан ' + restaurant.restaurant_name.title())
restaurant.describe_restaurant()
restaurant.open_restaurant()
restaurant.set_number_served(15)
restaurant.served_nubmer()
restaurant.increment_number_served(4)   #Что я делаю здесь не так?
restaurant.served_nubmer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `increment_number_served()` не объявлена в классе. Она объявлена внутри функции `set_number_served()`, следовательно, видна только оттуда. Догадываюсь, что Вам нужно убрать лишние отступы.

```py
    #...
    def set_number_served(self, the_sum):
        self.number_served = the_sum
    def increment_number_served(self, total):
        self.number_served += total
```